# How to make a HTML browser using iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I'd like to make a small browser-type HTML page. 
Basically, I'd like to make a browser purely out of HTML.

In my opinion, it can be done. All I need is a simple browser- address bar, and maybe tabs.

The first part can be accomplished easily- using an iframe and an input field. 
I already have the code here:

```
    <script>
        (function(d){
            var init = function(){
                var form = d.getElementById("my_form"), input = d.getElementById("url"), iframe = d.getElementById("browser");
                form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
                    var val = input.value;
                    if(val) {
                        iframe.src = "//" + val;
                        console.log(val);
                    }
                    e.preventDefault();
                }, false);
            };
            d.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
        })(document);
    </script>

    <form method="post" target="browser" id="my_form">
<input style="width:120%;" placeholder="Put the website here (eg. &quot;example.org&quot;)" name="url" id="url" type="text" />         

            <input style="width:8%;" name="submit" type="button" value="Go" />





    <iframe name="browser" frameBorder="0" id="browser" src="" style="height:100%; width:100%"></iframe>
```

**EDIT:**
THe question about google was simply out of curiosity. Below is the question I want answered!

I could easily affix the input field to the top of the page to seem like an address bar, leaving only the tab issue. I know it's possible to have tabs using jQuery(which is not my strong suit)- however, how can I open and close tabs? (Like in an actual web browser)

**Also**, I'm not concerned about the fact that some sites may not show up in the iframe- this is intended to be for demonstrational purposes, so please don't worry about the "validity" of my idea/code.

Thanks!

Comment: check the console output and you'll see that google doesn't allow itself to be iframed

Comment: anything that blocks iframes won't work in your "browser", like google properties, which use the xframeoptions header, but there's other techniques also. another issue with the idea is that you have no way to update the URL bar from a link click due to SOP

Comment: It can be done however there are some problems that you simply wont be able to fix, such as the one you found and framebusters that have framebusterbusters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google chooses to set some headers which prevent it from being in an iframe.
Check console:

```html
<iframe src='https://google.com'></iframe>
```

It reads

```
Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Comment: This answers why google doesn't load, but doesn't answer how to create a 'browser' in JS/HTML

Comment: Also, if you're going to downvote, at least leave a comment on why.